# How do I allow users to insert youtube videos in google slides

Tags: youtube, google-workspace-for-business, google-slides, g-suite-administrator, embed

I am an administator of a google education account. Recently teachers have been unable to insert youtube videos by URL in Google Slides. They are getting the message "You can't insert YouTube videos do to your school admin settings". I have not made any changes to this capability as an admin, and I don't know what settings are preventing this.

[image: "You can't insert YouTube videos do to your school admin settings"]

I know that Google has made a change recently to prevent users marked as "under 18" from adding youtube videos to slides. It has occurred to me that Google might think that the orgs with the teachers are under 18, but if that's the reason I don't know where to change that setting.

How do I allow teachers in my organization to add youtube videos by URL to google slides presentations?

Answer (score 1):

For other people who have this problem, here is why it's happening and the solution.

Google made a change that prevents people under 18 from adding youtube videos to slides, not sure why. When they created the age based setting everyone is listed as 'under 18' by default.

To fix it in Google Admin go to Account Settings. At the bottom click on 'Age based access settings.' Choose the org you want to apply settings to on the left and then click on 'All users are over 18' then save it. It takes a bit to propagate[image: Change age in Google Admin]